# Repeat ->select tag in play framework

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, playframework-2.0

This is code i have written to populate list of option from other class

```
@select(
    studentForm("friends[0].id"),
    options(Teacher.options),

    '_label -> "Teacher", '_default -> "-- Choose a Teacher --",
    '_showConstraints -> false
    )
```

with this code i m able to save selected teacher in database.
but i want to have one button next to this so that this dropdown can added/repeat into form again.

Comment: solve this question partially by using javascript .click(function() but not able to save in corresponding field in database.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of Javascript, as said above.
Ideally, using Jquery as well.

The idea is: Get the last select component, increase it's index name, then aappen it to the form.

EX:

http://jsfiddle.net/2powjxjv/

```
window.copyLastOne = function() {

    //Get a clone of the last select element
    var $lastSelectClone = $("#yourform").find("select:last").clone();

    //Change it's name so list is rightly filled
    $lastSelectClone.attr('name', function(i, id) {
        return id.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(match, number) {
            return "[" + (+number + 1) + "]";
        })
    });

    $("#yourform").append($lastSelectClone);




}
```

Of course you'll have to make it looks betters, lmfao, but that's a begin.

Hope it help you.